# eclipse not opening after jdk update

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just updated jdk to `jdk1.8.0_271` and it was installed in the `Java` folder with  `jdk-14.02` .
I then deleted jdk1.8.0_271 since I have the new jdk and modified the environment variable to the new jdk `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin` but I keep getting :

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ?

UPDATE :
I modified the path in eclipse.ini to `jdk1.8.0_271` and now I get

[image]

Comment: And then you also made sure to update your `JAVA_HOME` etc. variables properly, too?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I deleted the old path and created a new path in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin I called it JAVA_PATH should it be called PATH ?

Comment: `JAVA_PATH` is not `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: isnt this just a name ?

Comment: If I have a program that looks for `JAVA_HOME`, and I create a variable called `MONKEY_CAKE`, you think that program's going to know? Java _needs_ a variable called `JAVA_HOME` set to the correct value, in order to properly run. It's very much not just "a" name, it's the _only_ name it can be =)

Comment: That second dialog is quite clear, the version of Eclipse you are using needs at least Java 11 to run, Java 8 is not enough.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Java itself doesn't need the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, that is just a convention that a lot of Java tools rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following configuration (better to do in the beginning) in the `PATH` environment variable:

```
;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;
```

Optionally, put the following configuration in `JAVA_HOME` environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
```

**Alternatively**,

Put the following configuration in `JAVA_HOME` environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2
```

Then, append the following configuration (better to do in the beginning) in the `PATH` environment variable:

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

Comment: @Arvid Kumar Anivash I still get the second screenshot as a result

Comment: @vasilis123 - Move `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin` to the top in the list of environment variables. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: you did not include \bin in your answer . Should I add it ?

Comment: @vasilis123 - In my answer, it's there is the `PATH` variable. `JAVA_HOME` should not have `\bin` in it. `JAVA_HOME` means the installation directory of Java.

Comment: I moved %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the top . The result is the same

Comment: @vasilis123 - If you have set `JAVA_HOME` incorrectly, moving `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the top won't resolve the problem. Add `;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin;` at the beginning of the `PATH` variable (which is the first method mentioned in the answer) and try again. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225876/discussion-between-vasilis-123-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled jdk 14.02 and changed the path back to it . Now eclipse opens